# execute a code in the last 100 millisecond of a countdown

Tags: javascript

I have a countdown running continuously from 10 to 1 second and I need to execute a code in a precious moment.

Example: if the countdown is 2 seconds, I need to execute a code in the last 100 milliseconds of the 2 seconds, but when the countdown is again 2 seconds it needs to be executed again and again.

Here is the code I tried:

```
// for testing this code with countdown on console go to 
//https://www.xul.fr/ecmascript/settimeout.php

function miseEnAttente() {
  // here I should wait 900 millisecond before i execute the code 
  setTimeout(fonctionAExecuter, 900); //On attend avant d'exécuter la fonction
  //fonctionAExecuter();
}

function fonctionAExecuter() {
  console.log('code executed now ');
}
var boucle;

boucle = setInterval(function() {
    //boucle should work all the time and check the countdown if its 2 second or not
  var compteur1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('bip').innerHTML, 10);
  if (compteur1 === 2) {
    // clearInterval(boucle);
    // i tried the clearinterval but it work only once , when the countdown is 2 seconde again i will not execute
    /** i tried to sleep the code here but its same result as settimeout
    function setSleep(ms) {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }
    async function Display() {
      console.log('Wait for 900 ms!');
      await setSleep(900);
      console.log('After 900 ms!');
    }
    Display();
    fonctionAExecuter();
}
**/
}, 10)
```

To be more clear:

The countdown is always running from 10 to 1 second and then it go back to 10.
I need to execute a code if the countdown is 2 second for ever not only once.

Comment: Take a step back and really think about your problem. Don't try to combine your actions into a single `setInterval`. You have one interval for 2 seconds, and one interval for 1900 milliseconds... you see what I mean?

Comment: Be aware that the single-threaded nature of JS means precise timings cannot be guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using two timeouts or intervals I'd recommend a different way which goes a little something like this:

- get the start time , which is the current time in milliseconds
- get the target time, which is simply the current time + 10000 milliseconds
- set up a single interval which fires every ~20 ms
- inside it's callback function, check the difference between the current time and the target time. If there's <=2100ms left do your action and ultimately stop the interval if it reached 0 or below.

Here's an example (Just click on 'Run code snippet'):

```js
let seconds;
let targetTime;
let difference;
let codeExecuted;
let myInterval;

function test() {
  difference = targetTime - Date.now();
  if (parseInt((difference) / 1000) != seconds) {
    seconds = parseInt((difference) / 1000);
    document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML += seconds + ".. "

  }
  if (!codeExecuted && difference <= 2100) {
    document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML += "execute code "
    codeExecuted = true;
  }
  if (difference <= 0) {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    reset();
  }
}

function reset() {
  let currentTime = Date.now();
  seconds = 10;
  codeExecuted = false;
  targetTime = currentTime + seconds * 1000
  myInterval = setInterval(test, 20);
}
reset();
```

```html
<span id="myText"></span>
```

Comment: thanks for you help , but my counter is always running if it get to 0 seconde i will go back to 10 second so i need to execute the code for every time that the timer is 2 second not only once

Comment: Well, you can simply wrap the initialization of the timer inside a function and call it again if the counter reaches zero. I've modified the example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code does what you need. First we use `setInterval` to run every 2s or however long you need. Inside that code we create a `setTimeout` for the amount of time the interval is running on minus 100ms. I've put in some logs to be able to check the numbers.

```
const time = 2000
setInterval(() => {
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    clearTimeout(timer)
    const date = new Date()
    console.log(
      `Fires in the last 100 milliseconds. M:S:MS = ${date.getMinutes()}:${date.getSeconds()}:${date.getMilliseconds()}`,
    )
  }, time - 100)

  const date2 = new Date()
  console.log(
    `Main timer, fires every ${time} milliseconds. M:S:MS = ${date2.getMinutes()}:${date2.getSeconds()}:${date2.getMilliseconds()}`,
  )
}, time)
```

It's worth bearing in mind that time in javascript is not 100% reliable, especially setTimeout and setInterval. If you have a long running task inside a setInterval, one that takes the computer longer than the interval to complete, the next run in the interval will not run at exactly the time you wanted.